# Send Google Assistant/Alexa commands to my private server

Tags: alexa, google-assistant

We are in the process of building an IoT smart switch that can be controlled via WiFi and Google Assistant/Alexa similar to Sonoff. We are stuck in a few spots, where I thought you guys could help.

1. Is it possible to get the voice commands of the user to my private server and then send some data back to the assistant?
2. Also, is it possible to send a command to the smart switch directly from my private server after processing the commands?

It would be of great help if you could also provide me with details on the technologies I would be needing in order to develop this framework. I have good experience in developing Android and Web applications.

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question? Both Amazon and Google have very detailed docs about how their smart home APIs work. As it stands your question is far too broad